# TTURLMap with query strings ? (NSNull length error)

Tags: ios, url-routing, three20

I'm using three20 in my project and I'm trying to add this route to my url mapping :

[map from:@"onefeat://missions?(initWithArgs:)"toSharedViewController:[MissionListController class]];

But the app fails at launch with an -[NSNull length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2a10cd8 error.

Isn't there anyway to have a catchall url and then parse the query myself ?

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
[map from:@"onefeat://missions?missions=(initWithArgs:)" toSharedViewController:[MissionListController class]];
```

For an extensive list of samples you can see the TTNavigatorDemo demo under the samples folder in three20

Comment: Hmmm, the thing is, I want my url to look like : onefeat://missions?time=7days&category=artist and from the initWithArgs method, read the keypair values.

Comment: Here is how you use multiple parameters:This extends for multiple parameters, also. Let's say we want to display a specific page in MenuController.

[map from:@"tt://menu/(initWithMenu:)/(page:)"
  toSharedViewController:[MenuController class]];
Opening "tt://menu/1/5" will call

[[MenuController alloc] initWithMenu:1 page:5]

Comment: For a very good documentation see http://three20.info/article/2010-10-06-URL-Based-Navigation

Comment: From what I see in your comment, the url is then stating implicitly what are the options for. I really do want to have a readable url, where any item can be optional.

The way I'm tackling it now is : onefeat://missions?args=(initWithArgs:)
And my url look like onefeat://missions?args=time:7days&page:2
Not really perfect though.

Comment: Well, you simply can't have it all ;)